C# Directory.Exists returns true, although the folder does't exist
I can't figure out why there is an error in the result of the Directory.Exists method. It returns the result true, even though the folder does not exist. In debug mode, the path looks like this.
I tried to read solutions to this problem, but nothing helped.
DirectoryExists("c:temp\\foo") returns true when directory doesn't exist!

Please share a [mcve]

Open a command prompt. cd c:\  ENTER. dir thenameofyourfolder /s /ad ENTER. Please share the output.

Finds the desired folder with a different path c:\Users\ivano\AppData\Local\Packages\891f64ca-b806-4e53-ae51-048a7a13da49_dep6axykptwhy\LocalCache\Roaming

Is this some kind of UWP app, or packaged with MSIX or something? There might be some redirection going on, i.e. the folder exists to your App, because Windows applies folder redirection due to sandboxing. Make a full search of your PC for "SystemOfThermometry3" to see if it's somewhere else where it might be redirected.

@Lennart Unfortunately Windows File Search is useless for that task, so I (strongly) recommend VoidTools Everything for that purposes.

Apps delivered through packages like UWP, MAUI, are isolated from each other so a badly written application can't read or worse, mangle the files of another. Part of this includes redirecting attempts to read from the wrong folder into an appropriate temporary one. That's not new either. That's the same reason Windows doesn't allow applications to write to Program Files. Developers still tried to do so and caused damages, by forcing users to elevate privileges. So Windows now redirects such attempts to other folders. This may have started in Windows 7 or 8. That's not new either

Can you guarantee that the user the app is running as, and the user you're running as when claiming "the directory doesn't exist" are the same user, subject to the same security cnotext? Also, are you deducing "it doesnt exist" by opening C:, double clicking Users, double clicking Ivano and then seeing no AppData? I ask because AppData is hidden so you won't see it.. But it you type AppData in the address bar you will nav into it
